# How can I set up Landscape on Premis if the package is missing?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, landscape

Following the directions here https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem  I attempted to setup Landscape on Premise,  but the `landscape-server-quickstart` is missing.

```
$ sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart
```

---

```
$ apt-cache search landscape
landscape-client - The Landscape administration system client
landscape-common - The Landscape administration system client - Common files
gff2aplot - pair-wise alignment-plots for genomic sequences in PostScript
gimp-plugin-registry - repository of optional extensions for GIMP
hedgewars - Funny turn-based artillery game, featuring fighting hedgehogs!
libcitygml-bin - Utils of libcitygml - citygmltest
libcitygml-dev - Static and header files of libcitygml
libcitygml2 - Open source C++ library for parsing CityGML files
libunity-core-6.0-9 - core library for the Unity interface
libunity-core-6.0-dev - Core library for the Unity interface - development files
muttprint - Pretty printing of mails
python-txlongpoll - Long polling HTTP frontend for AMQP
r-cran-treescape - GNU R Statistical Exploration of Landscapes of Phylogenetic Trees
saga - System for Automated Geoscientific Analyses
stellarium - real-time photo-realistic sky generator
thin-client-config-agent - Retrieve the list of remote desktop servers for a user.
unity - Interface designed for efficiency of space and interaction.
unity-schemas - Interface designed for efficiency of space and interaction.
unity-services - Services for the Unity interface
xmountains - Fractal landscape generator for X
runescape - Multiplayer online game set in a fantasy world
landscape-api - Tool to access the Landscape API
```

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 17.10
Release: 17.10
Codename: artful

Answer (score 1):

Before running `sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart` you need to add Landscape PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/17.03
sudo apt update
```

Also, please keep in mind that Landscape server is available for Xenial (16.04) or lower. If you are using 17.10 or 18.04 you will not be able to find landscape-server-quickstart.

Hope this will help!

Comment: apt-cache madison landscape-server-quickstart
landscape-server-quickstart | 17.03.4-0ubuntu1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: oh hmm, sorry. I was trying it on 17.10. Why isn't it in the package list on Launchpad? I guess I don't understand those pages

Comment: No worries @Zanna. 17.03 is referring to the version of Landscape repo. https://help.landscape.canonical.com/ It can be confusing with Ubuntu versions as naming convention is very similar :)   File that Walter is looking for is here http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu/pool/main/l/landscape-server/

Comment: yes I realised that. I added the right PPA :) I mean I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, and the package was not found, so I guess it's not available for 17.10/Artful

Comment: Yes, you are right :) Landscape server (as it stands today) is available for up to 16.04 
landscape client, however, can be found in all versions up to 18.04

Comment: Thank you.  This was it.  I have 17.10.  I thought I had 17.04.  My bad.  Thank you for the answer!